# mount remote filesystem, that needs local network access: use sshuttle and sshfs in single bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to remotely mount a filesystem for which I need a vpn connection.
I can already do this with:

```
sudo sshuttle --dns --remote user@needvpn.de --daemon --pidfile=/tmp/sshuttle.pid 140.181.60.0/24 10.12.0.0/16
sleep 2
sshfs user@machineBehindVPN.de/ /home/b/gsi -C -o reconnect,auto_cache,follow_symlinks && echo "mounted successfully"
```

I made this in a bash script. Howver. It does never work the first time.
In order for this to work, I currently have to execute the above,
then execute

```
fusermount -u /mount/path || echo "unmounting failed.. lazy undmount    is executed" && fusermount -uz /mount/path && echo "with success"
```

and then execute the first part again.

Can this be avoided somehow?
Thanks :)

Comment: you are using the form `cmd1 || echo a && cmd2 && echo b` You should know that it is equivalent to `cmd1 || echo a; cmd2 && echo b`. You should tell us what you mean by `It does never work the first time`

Comment: Hi thanks for the hint with || and &&.

"Never works the first time" means, the sshfs command returns
"read: Connection reset by peer" after a minute or so.

Comment: Try increasing your `sleep` value. If that doesn't help, try un-mounting BEFORE launching `sshuttle` and see if that changes anything. If nothing helps, then you should try to update your `sshuttle`/`sshfs` programs to see if a bug has been fixed... And create a bug report otherwise.

Comment: tried with wait + sleep 120.

I run sshuttle (0.54-2) on debian jessie and there is no newer version in debian available. Thanks so far